# Using CLion, only "main.cpp" being built

Tags: c++, cmake

I've been working on a project in CLion for quite some time now (over a month). All of a sudden, CLion will not build all of my files... When I run my program, my messages build looks like this:

```
Scanning dependencies of target main.cpp
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.cpp.dir/Custom_Types.cpp.o
[ 22%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/main.cpp
ld: library not found for -l*.cpp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
make[3]: *** [../bin/main.cpp] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.cpp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.cpp.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [main.cpp] Error 2
```

Great... what the flippin fireworks is going on? This is what my CMake looks like...

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(Crazy_Sniper)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -fpermissive")

find_package (OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package (GLUT REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}  ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES
        *.cpp
        *.h
        )

add_executable(main.cpp ${SOURCE_FILES} Custom_Types.cpp)

target_link_libraries (main.cpp ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARIES} 
mdl pthread)
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? I've looked through countless forums, and I cannot seem to find someone with a similar problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Update! I've managed to get CLion to build my files, but main still does nothing... I try simply printing something out, and the console does nothing. I get an error code 11 for some reason...?

Thank you!

Comment: I would not name my target `main.cpp`.

Comment: How come @drescherjm ?

Comment: In CMake **targets** are not the files, so they do not have *extension*. Name your target as `main` and check (via `message()`) that *SOURCE_FILES* variable contains what do you expect.

Comment: I see... Thanks, I'll try that @Tsyvarev